# Angular 5 routing cannot Get when deployed to real hosting

Tags: angular, routes, router

I'm building angular 5 web app following instructions, i defined all my routes in app.module.ts

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { 
        path:'chat-user-dashboard',
        component:ChatUserDashboardComponent, 
        canActivate:[ChatAuthGuard]
      },
      {path:'contact-us', component:ContactUsComponent},
      {path:'about-us', component:AboutUsComponent},
      {path:'not-found',component:NotFoundComponent},
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found' }
    ])
  ],
```

in local server all works good, when click on link it navigates to the correct page and when just paste url with some route example https://example.com/login it works good the problem is when i deploy it to hosting service it works only when clicking on RouterLink and if i paste complete url i says CannotGet/login...

This is how i user RouterLink in Html

```
 <a class="nav-link" routerLink='about-us'>about us</a>
```

i searched for solution and from what i understood the problem is that browser cannot find those pages because Angular dont have them and use own routing service and that i need to define always fallback to index.html
and i do have fallback path as you can see above

```
{path:'not-found',component:NotFoundComponent},
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found' }
```

also tried like this
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }

but instead not found page i get Cannot Get page
Any idea?

Comment: check your base url try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50132558/4399281

Comment: you need to setup a URL rewrite to point all server-side requests to the angular HTML file

Comment: @pixelbits and how to do this?

Comment: no doesn't help @FatehMohamed

Comment: You have to redirect all 404 to `/index.html` on your server, not your frontend. How to achieve that depends on which server you use

Comment: The problem that this website i hosting currently on *free hosting and i don't have access to this configurations